# Systemd run daemon at boot like System V

Tags: linux, boot, debian, systemd, daemon

I'm configuring a Java app to run at boot using jsvc, following [this tutorial](http://www.neilson.co.za/creating-a-java-daemon-system-service-for-debian-using-apache-commons-jsvc/) which uses `systemv` (init.d). I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, which uses `systemd`, and am having a hard time finding **exactly** what I need to do to have it **run at boot**, and **stop at shutdown**.

So far I know I need to create a service with `Type=forking` as the `jsvc_exec` command which starts/stops the app forks once it has run.

What else do I need to include to have it work in a similar way to the systemv script from the tutorial?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
 [Unit]
 Description=Description of daemon
 After=network.target

 [Service]
 #WorkingDirectory=/path/to/program/
 #User=
 #Group=
 Type=forking

 ExecStart=/path/to/program/program start
 ExecStop=/path/to/program/program stop
 #PIDFile=/path/to/pid/file.pid
 #RestartSec=15
 #Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! One quick question, what is the PIDFile and where would I find it? Or does it not matter because the `#` comments the line?

Comment: #comments the line, uncomment what you need

Comment: in the Arch wiki it said if it's specified systemd can keep track of the main process, if I wanted to include this where would I find the PID file?

Comment: `/var/run/mydaemon.pid` I guess, from what I read in the tutorial...

Comment: Don't forget to `sudo systemctl enable daemon.service` where you replace `daemon.service` with the name of your service file, or it won't start at boot :)

Comment: `systemctl start daemon` works fine, but `systemctl enable daemon` spits out a load of errors from `insserv` about `incomplete LSB comment`, needing a `Default-Start` and `Default-Stop` entry (even if empty). There's also one at the bottom from `update-rc.d` saying `Default-Start contains no runlevels`

Comment: Try to remove all comments

Comment: in the ExecStart and ExecStop fields I had the script that I wrote previously in /etc/init.d/, adding `# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5` and `# Default-Stop: 0 1 6` in _that_ script seemed to work